# check if a value exists in my database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to check if a `URL` exists in my MySQL database table for example if `Url=exist`, `message=url` already exist

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '####';
    $dbpass = '#######';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $Url = $_POST['Url'];
    $email_data = $_POST['email_data'];
    $type_data = $_POST['type_data'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table ". "(Title,Url,email_data,type_data)"."VALUES('$Title','$Url','$email_data','$type_data')";
    mysql_select_db('dbname');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval ){
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
    mysql_close($conn);
} else {
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you have a question?

Comment: the question is how can i check if url already exist in my database table

Comment: $query = mysql_query('select url from table-name where url=$_post['url']');
if(mysql_fetch_rows != 0){
echo "URL allready Exists";

}else{
Insert Query

}

Comment: @KarthikKeyan . . . You really shouldn't encourage the use of a deprecated interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$sql = "SELECT Url FROM 'your_table_name' WHERE Url = $_POST['Url']";
```

Run this `sql` and if it is return `true` you can say its exist.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan Honestly I didn't see that though

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query('select url from table-name where url=$_post['url']');
if(mysql_fetch_rows($query) != 0){
echo "URL allready Exists";
}else{ 
Insert Query 
}
```

Hi, Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard know what you are doing by just looking at the code but if you wondering how to check if something is in the database you could do like this:

**PHP:**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE Url='$Url'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    echo "alreday exist";
}
```